# using cognito for authentication and custom authorizer for authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an serverless application which uses AWS Cognito, Lambda, and API Gateway.
The user signs in using AWS Cognito (with external identity provider) for user authentication and authorization.
The API gateway uses Cognito Authorizer to secure access to the lambda function.

The initial use case is simple, any request sent to API Gateway need to be authenticated with Cognito, and they are authorized to invoke the lambda function. As long as they can sign in, they can invoke the lambda.

Now I want to change the authorization. Even if the user is able to authenticate with Cognito, they must contain certain scopes in order to be authorized to invoke the lambda. These scopes can be fetch or checked in an external authz service. Cognito authorizer on the API gateway do not allow me to implement custom logic to call external authz service.

What is the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but may be useful for other people. Currently API Gateway provides JWT authorizer out of the box and it allows to specify authorized scopes.

> API Gateway evaluates the following token claims:
>
> - kid – The token must have a header claim that matches the key in the jwks_uri that signed the token.
> - iss – Must match the issuer that is configured for the authorizer.
> - aud or client_id – Must match one of the audience entries that is configured for the authorizer.
> - exp – Must be after the current time in UTC.
> - nbf – Must be before the current time in UTC.
> - iat – Must be before the current time in UTC.
> - scope or scp – The token must include at least one of the scopes in the route's authorizationScopes.

AWS CLI:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-authorizer \
    --name <authorizer-name> \
    --api-id <api-id> \
    --authorizer-type JWT \
    --identity-source '$request.header.Authorization' \
    --jwt-configuration Audience=<audience>,Issuer=https://cognito-idp.<us-east-2>.amazonaws.com/<userPoolID>
```

```
aws apigatewayv2 update-route \
   --api-id <api-id>  \
   --route-id <route-id>  \
   --authorization-type JWT \
   --authorizer-id <authorizer-id> \
   --authorization-scopes user.email
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) for this use case.

In your lambda you can first authenticate your incoming token [(example)](https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer) and once authentication is successful you can check authorization scopes using authz service.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've added the authorizer on the API Gateway console, you'll be given the option to select scopes as well.